# Can I use Stripe test mode without verification?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, stripe-payments

I am developing a mini asp.net mvc project for my subject in University. My project is an ecommerce project and I want to connect it with Stripe gateway. But I can't verify my Stripe account. So what I want to know is: Can I use Stripe test mode without verify my account?

Comment: this is a question that is better to ask Stripe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you can use Stripe's test mode without verifying your account.  Test mode will work immediately upon creation of a new Stripe account.